# Is there a way to iterate through s3 object content using a SQL expression?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I would like to iterate through each s3 bucket object and use a sql expression to find all the content that match the sql.

I was able to create a python script that lists all the objects inside my bucket.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucketname')
startAfter = 'bucketname/directory'
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    print(obj.key)
```

I was also able to create a python script that uses a sql expression to look through the object content.

```
import boto3

S3_BUCKET = 'bucketname'

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

var1 = 'aj9c03869'
var2 = 'b3bu11043'


r = s3.select_object_content(
        Bucket=S3_BUCKET,
        Key='name_of_object',
        ExpressionType='SQL',
        Expression='select * from s3object s where s.\"serialnumber\" in (%r,%r) ' % (var1,var2),
        OutputSerialization={'JSON': {}},
        InputSerialization={
        'CompressionType': 'GZIP',
        'JSON': {
            'Type': 'DOCUMENT'
    } }, )


for event in r['Payload']:
    if 'Records' in event:
        records = event['Records']['Payload'].decode('utf-8')
        print(records)
```

I would like to create a loop that goes through each bucket object, uses the sql expression to find the data within the object, and returns all the matches.

--Edit:

The reason why I am trying to query all the objects is to find content within the objects and delete specific data. I appreciate the answers about Athena but I don't think that would work in my case.

Comment: _WHY_ do you wish to do this? There might be a better way to achieve your purpose (eg using Amazon Athena). Please Edit your question and tell us more about what you are wanting to achieve from this process.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Amazon Athena – Interactive SQL Queries for Data in Amazon S3

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at S3 Batch Operations which will allow you to execute your python code (deployed to lambda) on all the objects in your bucket(s)

With this solution, you won't need to list the objects in the bucket but can have AWS run your script on all of your objects.

Answer (score 0):

S3 Select is also an option but Athena would be easier.