# how to query all objects in a bucket with s3.select_object_content?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I need to search many s3 objects for a text string in just the first line. I get how to do it for one object, and separately I can list all objects in a bucket, but I'm having trouble putting them together.

To get the content from just one file, I have this:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
sql_stmt = """select * from s3object limit 1"""

req = s3.select_object_content(
Bucket="some-bucket",
Key="some_file",
ExpressionType='SQL',
Expression=sql_stmt,
InputSerialization = {'CSV': {'FileHeaderInfo': 'NONE'}},
OutputSerialization = {'CSV': {}})
```

It returned the first line, so great. But can this work with the usual methods to traverse all objects, like paginator? I couldn't get it to work.

Someone asked this question last year and the answer was to use Athena, which I looked at and again, it works for one object but I don't see how to do for many objects. So please don't mark me as a duplicate because it wasn't actually resolved.

[Is there a way to iterate through s3 object content using a SQL expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56069436/is-there-a-way-to-iterate-through-s3-object-content-using-a-sql-expression)

So the question is, how to do the above for all objects in a bucket? Can Athena do that? I'm not clear how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain better what you want to achieve? Athena is great if the data in the files have some meaning and the first line is there for a reason (time, event...).

Comment: I need to check if CSVs have any customer account info, so I just need to search "customer" in the headers, for example. That's why I only need the first line.